# Highcharts custom x-axis labels

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts, highcharts

I currently have a column chart, with data from my database of how much a user has spent per day. But I can't seem to change the labels for each piece of data for the x-axis, I want them to be the dates of each day of expenditure in my database, instead they are currently showing January 1 00:00:00, and I can't seem to change them. I have tried pointStart: Date.UTC(), but that seems to crash the whole thing. The dates in my database are stored in the format Y-m-d so they should switch straight over without a problem. Ideally I would like each day to be labelled with the day it represents in my database, which I do have fields storing that info in my db. Or alternatively just get the pointStart to be the day of the first day in my db and then increment each one by a day.
This is the current code for my chart:

```
var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'chart2',
            type: 'column'
        },
      title: {
            text: 'Amount spent each day'
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },

        series: [{
         name: 'Amount spent',
            data:  [<?php echo join($trip_total, ',') ?>],
        }]
    });
```

This picture shows my chart, and as you can see the x-axis are labelled from January 1 00:00:00, which is what I need to change.
[image]

Comment: Highcharts displays x-labels this way when the x axis type is datetime and it cant load the x axis values. The labels you are 1 jan 1970 (start of unix time) and then incremented by a millisecond. could you please post the value of this expression `<?php echo join($trip_total, ',') ?>`

Comment: that expression is an array of values from my database, which are the total amounts of money spent each day, which it displays in the graph

Comment: What else could it be? I wanted to see the exact format.

Comment: the issue is not with that part though, that bit works fine. It's the x-axis labels that I need to change

Comment: If Highcharts cant read your x axis values then it uses the default ones, which is what it is doing right now. That is why I wanted to have a look.

Comment: how would I get it to read my date values? because I tried pointStart: Date.UTC(<?php echo $date1 ?>), but that didn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106368/discussion-between-rahul-sharma-and-eth3king).

Comment: The Date.UTC is not executable in the json and PHP. The solution is parse data when you load that from database. To do that, call query to database, iterate on each element and convert dates to timestamp by strtotime() function in PHP. As a result you receive the UNIX timestamp, which requires to be multiplied by 1000 (timestamps in JS are in miliseconds).